# How to get upload images in a other folder? express static issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express

I currently have 2 folders, one named project that contain a public folder and a server folder. I am currently using a post method for uploading files (images). These are my 2 folders path :
`project/router/index.js` and `project/client/public/uploads`

I have use app.use(express.static('public')); so my `project/router` could have access to my public folder. The problem is I don't really know how to tell my function the path to use. When I do
`` await fs.writeFile(`http://localhost:8080/uploads/${request.files[0].originalname}`, data); `` My router use the port 3000 and my client folder use the port 8080. At the end my function use the wrong path :

`server\http:\localhost:8080\uploads\IMG_20200813_0006.jpg'` and I want to use this one instead `project/client/public/uploads`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await fs.writeFile('http...') is a double fail :)

if you want to use await you need to use promises :
`await fs.promises.writeFile()`

you can't write to http, it makes no sens. For this you should make a proper request using node's http module or a simpler one, axios for exemple.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```

why not use directly that ?

```
await fs.promises.writeFile(`project/client/public/uploads/${request.files[0].originalname}`, data)
```

Comment: When I use this it said that it goes in this path ... ``project/server/project/client/public/uploads/`` It stays in the same path

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I fix my problem by changing my path for the uploads. I put it in my server/public folder and to get the images I have use  `v-bind:src="'http://localhost:3000/uploads/' + publication.image">`